# Get all elements but the first from an array

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a one-line easy linq expression to just get everything from a simple array except the first element?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= contents.Length - 1; i++)
    Message += contents[i];
```

I just wanted to see if it was easier to condense.

Comment: Instead of concatenating strings, it is better to use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Yes, [Enumerable.Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) does what you want:

```
contents.Skip(1)
```

However, the result is an IEnumerable<T>, if you want to get an array use:

```
contents.Skip(1).ToArray()
```

Comment: It is also possible to wrap the `contents` array in a new instance of the `ArraySegment<>` struct. At the time the above answer was written, that was not particularly useful, but since .NET 4.5 the `ArraySegment<>` implements `IList<>`, `IReadOnlyList<>` and their base interfaces (including `IEnumerable<>`), so you can for example pass an `ArraySegment<>` to `string.Join`.

Comment: As much as I hate Linq, I decided I can tolerate this, only because it's being ran in a static constructor, once per application boot, so the performance overhead is non existent.

Answer (score 7):

The following would be equivalent to your `for` loop:

```
foreach (var item in contents.Skip(1))
    Message += item;
```

Comment: did you want _`var item`_ ??